# Add two stacklayots in a frame - code behind (not xaml)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a stacklayout that is horizontally but i need to add a button that is supposed to be above the other items in the frame.

I tried adding another stacklayout but it complains.

```
var stackLayout = new StackLayout
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Children = {image, label}
                };

                var buttonStackLayout = new StackLayout
                {
                    Children = {addButton}
                };

                return new ViewCell { View = stackLayout};
```

When I try to do this:

```
return new ViewCell { View = stackLayout && buttonStackLayout};
```

It says I cant have operands of 2 stacklayouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View = stackLayout && buttonStackLayout is wrong.

You need use :

```
View = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = {stackLayout , buttonStackLayout}
            };
```