# Add listview and stacklayout to a frame in code behind (not xaml)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this line of code to add the listview in the frame:

```
frame.Content = containerListView;
```

However, I also have a button inside a stacklayout that I also want to be included in the frame.

I tried this but no luck:

```
frame.Content = containerListView && buttonStackLayout;
frame.Content = containerListView , buttonStackLayout;
```

This is not the same scenario as the other stack post because the other post adds 2 stacklayouts to a viewcell. I need to add a listview and stacklayout to a frames content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two stacklayots in a frame - code behind (not xaml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676285/add-two-stacklayots-in-a-frame-code-behind-not-xaml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create your `StackLayout` and `Button` then add add them as the content of your

```
//StackLayout
StackLayout buttonStack = new StackLayout()
{
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 10),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        BackgroundColor = "Gray" ,
};

//Button
Button btn = new Button() { Text = "Button", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center};
btn.Clicked += btn_Clicked; //don't forget to create the btn_Clicked event/method

buttonStack.Children.Add(btn);
```

**Edit**

```
private ListView GetListView(int index)
    {
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = //your list Source

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Margin = new Thickness(3);

        frame.Content = listView;
        return listView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but where do I add the listview to the frame.Content? I need buttonStack and containerListView to be in the content. @Oluwasayo Babalola

Comment: oh. If I understand you correctly, you need buttonStack and frame to be in a Listview?

Comment: Well more like, I need a button (not in the listview but above the listview) and a listview inside a frame. @Oluwasayo Babalola

Comment: frame.Content = listView; 

and then I need Button btn = new Button() to be inside the frame too. So I tried: 
frame.Content = listView + btn; Tried other things too but doesnt work. 
@Oluwasayo Babalola

Comment: @KalleP Since `btn` is already a child of `buttonStack`, you can create a new StackLayout, then set the children of your new StackLayout to be your listview and buttonStack. Then, you can do `frame.Content = //your_new_StackLayout;` Okay? Let me know if you need more help